# How can I improve performance of scramble code?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, performance, optimization

i need to complete the function scramble(str1, str2) that returns true if a portion of str1 characters can be rearranged to match str2, otherwise returns false. Which way I can improve performance of this code?
For example if I have 200k+ chars in str1 and str2 the performance is really bad.

```
bool scramble(const string& s1, const string& s2) 
{
    string reference = s2;
    string inputStr = s1;
    size_t refLen = reference.length();
    size_t lenCounter = 0;

    for (auto n = 0; n < reference.length(); n++)
    {
        auto tempLetter = reference[n];
        size_t letterPos = inputStr.find(tempLetter);
        if (letterPos != string::npos)
        {
            lenCounter++;
            inputStr.erase(letterPos, 1);
            if (lenCounter == refLen)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    if (refLen == lenCounter)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

This is a ready-made solution that meets my requirements. Idea of this solution provided by @Dave

```
bool scramble(const string& s1, const string& s2)
{
    string ref = s2;
    string input = s1;
    string result = "";
    char tempLetter = '\0';
 
    sort(ref.begin(), ref.end());
    sort(input.begin(), input.end());
   
    map<char, int> letters;

    for (auto n = 0; n < input.length(); n++)
    {
        tempLetter = input[n];
        map<char, int> ::iterator it = letters.find(tempLetter);
        if (it == letters.end())
        {
            letters.insert(make_pair(tempLetter, 0));
            letters.at(tempLetter) = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            letters.at(tempLetter) += 1;
        }
    }
    for (auto i = 0; i < ref.length(); i++)
    {
        tempLetter = ref[i];
        map<char, int> ::iterator it = letters.find(tempLetter);
        if (it != letters.end() && letters.at(tempLetter) >=0)
        {
            letters.at(tempLetter) -= 1;
            if (letters.at(tempLetter) < 0)
                return false;
            result.push_back(tempLetter);
        }
    }
    if (result!=ref)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @user12002570 No. Codereview is for reviewing working code. Code that does not meet performance requirements is not working.

Comment: Are you using compiler optimisations? What performance are you seeing? What performance do you expect? Please show a [mre]

Comment: Do you know how to check anagrams quickly? If not, look it up, it is quite a famous easy problem and everyone and their dog has a version.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Compilers rarely can optimise a quadratic algorithm into a linear one.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Normally you would be correct. However, [we have an exception for programs which do not scale](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5484). If the code works correctly (outputs correct values) on small inputs then the code would fall under our scale rules. Additionally, if you still do not believe me, I'd like to point you to our [time-limit-exceeded](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-limit-exceeded) tag. Thank you for helping us keep off-topic questions off Code Review.

Comment: Super cheap (and perhaps not so impactful) improvement: Right at the beginning you copy both `s1` and `s2`. `s1` may be ok, since you edit the copy later (is it a problem to destroy `s1`?), but you don't edit the copy of `s2` so why copy it.

Comment: That said, I believe the algorithm @n.m.couldbeanAI hinted at does not edit any of the input strings, so there no copy at all is required

Comment: @Frodyne Thank you for comment, I edited my code, but yes, this is not so impactful))

Comment: Welcome to Scicomp! One approach you could test would be to _sort_ the two strings and then start your lookup. That way you drastically reduce the time for negative results at the cost of sorting the two Strings. Try something like: 

std::sort(std::begin(array), std::end(array))

Comment: Btw, is there any restriction on the character set of `s1` and `s2`? Is it ASCII characters or full Unicode?

Comment: @MPIchael There is still a better way if your alphabet is small.

Comment: another Idea would be to do one pass where you count the ammount of "a", "b" ... and keep a table. Then you do the same for the second array. Then you check whether there are enough "a"'s and "b"'s in your array. This should reduce the complexity to be linear at the cost oft some accounting memory.

Comment: @Frodyne You have too high opinion of these code challenge sites.

Comment: Suggest to find a book for how to know your algorithm complexity in time and space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return false if the strings aren't the same length.

Use a counting hash.

For the first word, increment the count of each letter in your map. For the second, decrement the count of each letter.

While decrementing, return false if a letter would be decremented below zero. If you make it to the end, return true.

O(n) for n letters.

Instead of a counting hash, you could use an array of ints with 1 index per character in the relevant alphabet, and use this for counting.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer really helped me. I've optimised it for my case and it works perfect. Also thank you for not providing a ready-made solution, it's very good for my C++ learning)

Comment: "At the end, return false if the total isn't back down to zero"  Or early exit if `a.size() != b.size()`, in which case you don't need to do any hashing at all.

Comment: @BenVoigt Good point. Edited. Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need a map? I would use an array of counters for each letter.

Comment: @VladFeinstein That's what I meant by the final sentence: Instead of a counting hash, use an array of ints with 1 index per character." Is that unclear?

Answer (score 1):

I would write it a bit differently for 2 reasons:

1. Readability and maintainability
2. Complexity

Let's say that `m = sizeof s1;` and `n = sizeof s2;` and that `n` should be bigger then `m`.

Sorting the string first will cost you O(nlog(n)) but then, in one pass, you can get to your output, which means that my scramble function complexity is:

```
O(n+nlogn) = O(nlongn)
```

However, in your case, the complexity is `O(n*m)`.

This is how I would write it:

```
bool is_scramble(std::string s1, std::string s2) 
{
    if (s2.size() < s1.size()) return false;

    std::ranges::sort(s1);
    std::ranges::sort(s2);

    return std::ranges::includes(s2, s1);
}
```

As mentioned in the comment, you could do a count sort (under the limitations of ASCII or EBCDIC) which is even cheaper in terms of time complexity and then write the following code instead.

It does take extra storage of 256 bytes (with the limitation of ASCII or EBCDIC). IMHO, it less readable as well.

```
bool is_scramble2(std::string s1, std::string s2) 
{
    // s1 needs to be contain in s2
    if (s2.size() < s1.size()) return false;

    constexpr int maxChar = 256; // Assuming ASCII character set
    std::array<int, maxChar> count = {0};

    // Count the occurrences of each character in the string
    for (char c : s2) {
        count[static_cast<int>(c)]++;
    }

    for(const auto c : s1) {
        if (count[static_cast<int>(c)] <= 0) return false;
        count[static_cast<int>(c)]--;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Using counting sort would even be `O(256 * n)` (and even that sort part is not necessary, as only the count part is enough to check inclusion).

Comment: yep you are right but you assume ascii chars and you use 256 extra bytes

Comment: I don't assume ascii (EBCDIC would also be supported).

Comment: sorry you are right again ... will update my answer